# Echo Out Interger Differently If More Than Value PHP

Tags: php

So I'm creating a points system for my website which I want to change to an echo instead of the actual integer when shown on the users profile. 
For example: When the integer is lower than 1000 it displays as the actual number (lets say: 645). But when it is between 1000 and 1100, it will display as '1k' and so on. What I've got so far does work, but displays incorrectly and does seem a bit of a waste of space.. Is there any way to do this in a much simpler; faster way?

Thanks!

code:

```
<?php

   $points_disp = $user_data['points'];

   if($points_disp < 1000){
      echo $points_disp;
   } else if ($points_disp >= 1000){
      echo '1k';
   } else if ($points_disp >= 1200){
      echo '1.2k';
   } else if ($points_disp >= 1400){
      echo '1.4k';
   } else if ($points_disp >= 1600){
      echo '1.6k';
   } else if ($points_disp >= 1800){
      echo '1.8k';
   } else if ($points_disp >= 2000){
      echo '2k';
   }

?>
Edit: I figured out an easier way to do this;

code (for anyone else who needs to do this):

<?php
$points_disp = $user_data['points'];
$fdigit = substr($points_disp, 0, 1);
$sdigit = substr($points_disp, 1, 1);

if ($points_disp < 1000){
    echo $points_disp;
} else if ($points_disp >= 1000){
    echo $fdigit . "." . $sdigit . "k";
}

echo $num; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
if($points_disp < 1000){
     echo $points_disp;
} else if($points_disp >= 1000) {
     echo round($points_disp/1000,1) . "K";
}
```

Comment: I have rounded the value, check this once. This should help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use switch case:

```
$points_disp = $user_data['points'];

switch(true)
{
    case ($points_disp < 1000):
     $num = $points_disp;
     break;
    case ($points_disp > 1000 && $points_disp < 1100 ):
        $num = '1.2k';
        break;

    //...so on
}

echo $num;
```

Comment: is there a way to shorten this code so that i don't have to type out so much?